# SQL say that there are no rows with a certain value

Tags: sql-server, count

I'm new with SQL and I need your help.
I have a table with a `Name` column and a `Value` column.
This value represents a 3-values enum, let's say `Yes`, `No`, and `Maybe`.

I'm trying to count, for each name, how many times I have each value of the enum. Something like this:

```
Name1   Yes     3
Name1   No      1
Name1   Maybe   4

Name2   Yes     0
Name2   No      1
Name2   Maybe   2

Name3   Yes     1
Name3   No      0
Name3   Maybe   7
```

but there are times when I don't have any entry for a given name with a given value, and it doesn't show up. Shortly, when count is 0, I don't get the row.
And I have to put it in a stored procedure.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you all in advance!

P.S. I'm using SQL Server

EDIT:

What I tried is:

```
SELECT  Name,
        Value,
        COUNT(Value) as ValueCount
from Data
group by Name, Value
order by Name
```

Comment: Please give us some queries you've tried, along with how the results didn't match your expectations, and we'll help improve them.

Comment: another add: this code will be put in a stored procedure, if it makes difference (added this aspect in the article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two cte to get a list of all combinations you want to show, then do a left join with your original table.

```
WITH enum AS
(
  SELECT 'Yes' AS Value
  UNION
  SELECT 'No'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Maybe'
), combs AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT d.Name, e.Value
  FROM enum e, Data d
)
SELECT c.Name, c.Value, COUNT(d.Name) FROM combs c
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.Name = c.Name AND d.Value = c.Value
GROUP BY c.Name, c.Value
ORDER BY c.Name, c.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then use a `left join` to join in the values for counting:

```
SELECT n.Name, v.value, COUNT(d.value) as ValueCount
from (select distinct name from Data) n cross join
     (select distinct value from Data) v left join
     data d
     on d.name = n.name and d.value = v.value
group by n.Name, v.Value
order by n.Name;
```

You don't specify the database.  This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your table overall, it would be a lot cleaner like this:

```
Name    Yes    No    Maybe
__________________________

Bob     3      4       0
Tim     0      1       3
Jim     2      7       2
```

I know that's not really an answer to solving your problems but this table is much smaller and achieves the same results.

Comment: I know but I really need that layout

Answer (score 0):

Often when trying to count something that isn't there, it's best to join to a driver table, in this case, you need all name/value pairs to join against, created below in a simple `cte` using a `CROSS JOIN`, but you could pull the values in a number of ways:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT d1.name,d2.value
              FROM data d1
              CROSS JOIN data d2
              )

SELECT  cte.Name,
        cte.Value,
        COALESCE(COUNT(d.Value),0) as ValueCount
from cte 
LEFT JOIN Data d
  ON d.value = cte.value
  AND d.name = cte.name
group by cte.Name, cte.Value
order by cte.Name
```

Since this requires a `LEFT JOIN` any missing values will return `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` is used to show `0`.

Comment: This won't work. If a value of name is not Yes, No, or maybe, then it will still show, but that's not what he is asking for.

Comment: `Name3, No, 0` would not show up in your solution, because Name3 already gets matched on Yes and Maybe.